# How do I put a min and max value in an input text for a custom date

Tags: javascript, date, input

I would like to know how I can add a min value and a max value in my input text for a date.
The format that I would like to have is : dd/mm/yyyy

So I've put a maxlenght to my input and I have added automatically "/" after the user type 2 numbers.

When I test it, everything is fine but I still can write "67/34/8888" and not a correct date for example.

Here's my code :

```
<form method="post" action="#" id="formStep2">
<input type="text" id="txtDate" class="selector" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" maxlength="10" required />
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#txtDate").keyup(function(){
        if ($(this).val().length == 2){
            $(this).val($(this).val() + "/");
        }else if ($(this).val().length == 5){
            $(this).val($(this).val() + "/");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Is it possible to add something like :

```
 if ($(this).val().length == 2 && $(this).val().min == 1 && $(this).val().max == 31){...}
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Use a datepicker? Also, cache `$(this)` and reuse it. The creation of a `$(this)` object is a relatively heavy operation. Do it once `let $this = $(this)` and reuse `$this`.

Comment: `if ($(this).val().length == 2 && $(this).val().length >= 1 && $(this).val().length <= 31){...}` EDIT: just the logic, though there's of course better ways to do it..

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thank you very much for your advice with $(this) !
 I will look what I can do with a datepicker

Comment: Hi yezzz, thank you for your answer it seems really easy, I will test it :)

Comment: Well it's not the logic you need, I only inserted valid code. To add to Jeremy's answer you could also just use a var eg `var x = $(this).val().length; if (x == 2 && x >= 1 && x <= 31){...}`

Comment: Please don't try to control user input, it will make the control dysfunctional. Also, `this.value` is very much more efficient than `$(this).val()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using [`type="date"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date):

```html
<input type="date" min="1970-01-01" max="2017-06-08" required>
```

Comment: Hi André, 

Thank you for your answer, 

I wanted to avoid to use "type=date" because the format is mm/dd/yyyy I think, and I'm prohibited from using a calendar (like datepicker) but it's seems like I have no choice and it's clearly better to use type date. 

Thank you :)

Comment: The format is based on the OS locale settings, which you should respect as a good UX denizen.

Comment: According to [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#Browser_compatibility) (and testing), input type date isn't well supported, particularly among desktop browsers.